# How do you calculate a single Median for multiple columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate a single median for multiple columns in my dataframe.

So far I only found solutions that give me a median for each column.

My dataframe has the following form:

```
ID    Time1    Time2
1     4.5      6.5
2     3.5      5.5
```

So far all solutions will result in

```
Time1    Time2
4.0      6.0
```

but my desired result is a single value that is the median of both of those columns (5.0)

I will later have to do the same for mean, variance, and standard deviation, so a solution that is adaptable to those would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `base R` possibility could be:

```
median(stack(df[-1])$values)

[1] 5
```

Or:

```
median(stack(df[-1])[, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

We could `unlist` all column values ignoring the `ID` column

```
median(unlist(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `base R` option

```
median(t(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 5
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   select(matches('Time')) %>% 
   flatten_dbl %>%
   median
#[1] 5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Time1 = c(4.5, 3.5), Time2 = c(6.5, 
5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```